# PDF as iFrame src in Phonegap doesn't want to scroll

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe, scroll

I'm building an iOS application using Cordova (Phonegap). I want to display a pdf underneath some sort of navigation-bar. I was thinking of using an iFrame, and setting the src to a locally stored .pdf file.

Luckily: it loads the pdf.
Sadly: i can't get the iFrame to scroll. No css property has any influence on this.. i haven't tried iScroll, as i would like to stay away from JS frameworks as much as possible.

Any clues as what might be going wrong

Comment: Running into the same issue, how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a js driven solution working on iOS, I think you have to set  webkit css rule `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to your pdf iframe.

Check this article for a deeper discussion:
http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/blog/2012/05/strategies-for-the-iframe-on-the-ipad-problem/